# Verifying $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\arccos\sqrt{\frac{3^3}{2^5}}\,\right)=\cos\frac\pi5$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I can verify the equation using Excel. But is there another derivation?

$$\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\cos\left[\frac{1}{3}\arccos\left(\!\!\sqrt{\frac{3^3}{2^5}}\right)\right]=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)$$

Thank you for help.

Comment: 1) Find a third degree equation verified by $\cos \pi/5$. 2) Solve this equation by the trigonometric method.

Comment: In fact $\cos(\pi/5) =\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}$ which is half the golden ratio.

Comment: Heide, if you put more context in your question, I will write an answer. Please, read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) carefully and do it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\cos\left(\theta\right)$, where $\theta=\frac{1}{3}\arccos\left(\sqrt{\frac{3^3}{2^5}}\right)$.

By the triple angle formula, we have

$$4\cos^3(\theta) -3\cos(\theta)-\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} = 0.$$

i.e.  $u$ is a root of the cubic $$q(x) = 6\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x^3-3\sqrt\frac{3}{2}x-\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}.$$

or, after clearing coefficients,
$$ p(x)=8x^3-4x-1.$$

On the other hand, $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)$ is also a root of $p(x)$, as

\begin{align*}
p\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)\right)&=8\cos^3\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)-4\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)-1\\
&= 2\left(3\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{5}\right)\right)-4\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)-1\\
&= 2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)+2\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{5}\right)-1\\
&= 0.
\end{align*}

Factoring $p(x)$, we have

$$p(x)=(2x+1)(4x^2-2x-1).$$

We see that $p(x)$ has a unique positive root. Since $u$ and $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)$ are both positive, we must have $u=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)$.

Comment: Why didn't I try rational root theorem lol. Nice one